# Importing .csv files and saving as .dta

Tags: csv, import, stata

I have a folder containing a number of csv files, e.g. "leeds dz.csv", "leeds gh.csv", "leeds fr.csv". The first part of the file names is constant (i.e. always "leeds").

I want to import each to Stata individually, convert to .dta file and `save` it. Currently I have this code:

```
cd "etcetc"
clear
local myfilelist : dir . files"*.csv"
foreach file of local myfilelist {
drop _all
insheet using `file', comma
local outfile = subinstr("`file'",".csv","",.)
save "`outfile'", replace
}
```

The code works fine if I rename all the .csv files manually to delete the "leeds" part, ie if each .csv is named "dz.csv" instead of "leeds dz.csv" etc.

However, if I do not do this deletion I receive the error "invalid 'dz.csv' "

I'm guessing this has something to do with my 3rd line of code, in particular the "*.csv". But I'm unsure how to adapt the code/ why it won't allow me to import files with a space in the name?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
insheet using `file', comma
```

will be problematic with any filename containing spaces.

Try

```
insheet using "`file'", comma
```

The help for `insheet` is quite explicit on this:

> If filename is specified without an extension, .raw is assumed.  If your
>       filename contains embedded spaces, remember to enclose it in double
>       quotes.

Comment: Trawling a number of help files, and the original statement of the problem, suggests that you are not aware of using `set trace on` along with `set tracedepth 1` before executing your code to trace its excution, allowing you to narrow down the command issuing the error message in a case like this.

Comment: Hadn't come across 'set tracedepth 1' before- handy tip, thanks!